# How do you build a graph from a data frame using the igraph package?

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

Any way to build a graph ( igraph package ) from a Data Frame in R ?

The data frame contains node relationships.

```
    df = data.frame ( 
A = c("Berlin", "Amsterdam", "New York") , 
B = c("Munich", "Utrecht", "Chicago") 
)
```

Edges are :

```
Berlin -> Munich
Amsteram -> Utrecht
New York -> Chicago
```

Comment: Yes there is.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

igraph is very flexible and I'm sure there are a number ways to accomplish this. I found the tutorials provided on the [website](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) to be very helpful.

Here's one simple way to create a network plot from a data.frame:

```
library(igraph)

df <- data.frame(
  A = c("Berlin", "Amsterdam", "New York") , 
  B = c("Munich", "Utrecht", "Chicago"))

df.g <- graph.data.frame(d = df, directed = FALSE)

plot(df.g, vertex.label = V(df.g)$name)
```

[image]

**Note:** For current versions of `igraph` (as of Version 1.2.1), the `graph.data.frame()` function is changed to `graph_from_data_frame()`, which is the only function out of these two to appear [in the documentation](http://igraph.org/r/doc/). The `graph.data.frame()` function will still work, though.